# Bourbaki Algebraic Structures Question 4.8

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Second part unsolved.

Let $\mathrm A$ and $\mathrm A'$ be two groups and $\mathrm G$ a subgroup of $\mathrm{A\times A'}$. We write:
$\mathrm{N = G \cap (A \times \{e\}), H = pr_1(G)}$
$\mathrm{N' = G \cap (\{e\} \times A'), H' = pr_2(G)}$.

(a) Show that $\mathrm N$ is normal in $\mathrm H$ and $\mathrm N'$ is normal in $\mathrm H'$; define isomorphisms $\mathrm{H/N\to G/(N \times N') \to H'/N'}.$

Solution: Suppose $\mathrm g$ is in $\mathrm G$ and $\mathrm n$ is in $\mathrm N$, then $\mathrm {pr_1(gng^{-1}) = pr_1(g)npr_1(g)^{-1}}$ is in $\mathrm N$, hence $\mathrm N$ is normal in $\mathrm H$, in a similar manner we see that $\mathrm N'$ is normal in $\mathrm H'$; if $\mathrm pr_1(g)$ is in $\mathrm N$ then $\mathrm {pr_2(g) = pr_1(g)^{-1}g}$ is in $\mathrm N'$, hence the homomorphism from $\mathrm G$ to $\mathrm H/N$ sending $\mathrm g$ to $\mathrm {pr_1(g)N}$ has kernel equal to $\mathrm NN'$, by the first isomorphism theorem $\mathrm G/NN'$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm H/N$, in a similar manner $\mathrm G/NN'$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm H'/N'$.

(b) Suppose that $\mathrm {H = A}$, $\mathrm {H' = A'}$, that the groups $\mathrm A$ and $\mathrm A'$ are of finite length and that no quotient of a Jordan-Hölder series of $\mathrm A$ is isomorphic to a quotient of a Jordan-Hölder series of $\mathrm A'$. Show that $\mathrm{G = A \times A'}$.

Comment: What are your thoughts? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: Showing that $N$ is normal in $H$ and $N'$ is normal in $H'$ is a routine check, so you should at least be able to do that.

Comment: I cannot manage even this. It isn't clear to me why normality follows from the definitions.

Comment: I will look for a highlight function. Perhaps this will allow me to ask one question at a time without offending Bourbaki.

Comment: I'm stuck on the first part. 10 Hours of labor and I cannot verify. Each part of this question puzzles me however. I've very little intuition for isomorphism.

Comment: The isomorphism part is more difficult, but showing normality is straightforward. Let $h \in H$ and $n \in N$. You have to check that $h^{-1}nh \in N$.

Comment: I guess you could argue that this is a single problem in Bourbaki's book, so it is a single question.

Comment: Part (a) is just [Goursat's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goursat%27s_lemma). There is a slight problem in the notation, in that $H$ and $H'$ are in the factors and everything else in the product, but the intent is clear. Part (b) follows from part(a): we will have that $A/N$ is isomorphic to $A'/N'$. But because no terms of the Jordan-Holder series are isomorphic, that tells you that both of these groups are trivial, so $N=A\times\{e\}$, $N'=\{e\}\times A'$. Thus, $A\times\{e\},\{e\}\times A'\leq G$ hence $G=A\times A'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part (a) is nothing more than [Goursat's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goursat%27s_lemma).

In part (b), $G$ is a subdirect product. That means that it is the "graph"  of an isomorphism between a quotient $A/N$ of $A$ and a quotient $A'/N'$ of $A'$. But we are assuming that there are no terms of the Jordan-Holder series of $A$ that are isomorphic to terms of the Jordan-Holder series of $A'$. Since terms of the Jordan-Holder series of $A/N$ are part of the Jordan-Holder series of $A$, and similarly for $A'/N'$, we conclude that $A/N$ and $A'/N'$ are both trivial. That  is, $G$ contains both $A\times\{e\}$ and $\{e\}\times A'$, hence $G$ equals $A\times A'$.